# Долгая загрузка приложения asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет. Опубликовал приложение ASP.NET Core на Linux. Столкнулся с проблемой.
Первоначальная загрузка приложения занимает много времени. Время превышает несколько минут.

SPA-приложение. Клиент использует Vue.JS.
Подключается к PostgreSQL. В ресурсах содержится много изображений.

Причем загрузка медленная только при первом запуске.
Многостраничные приложения грузят быстрее.
Загрузка долгая и на Linux и на Windows серверах.

С чем это может быть связано? С приложением или сервером? Возможно ли это исправить или так и должно быть?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Если загрузка долгая на win&lin серверах разных провайдеров -- то тут однозначно дело не в провайдере и не в серверах, а в приложении. Попробуйте проверить у разных провайдеров, например, возьмите себе appharbor.com на недельку погонять free аккаунт и сравните. А в остальном - без вашего кода вряд ли что-то даст конкретные советы. Ну вот банальное: берите профилировщик и замеряйте что именно тормозит, а не гадайте на кофейной гуще.

Comment: долгая - это сколько? Что говорят логи? Первый запуск может быть дольше из за компиляции байт кода в нативный код.

Comment: Если дело в компиляции, возможно ли это исправить? Я видел, что проблема может быть в `<compilation debug="true" />`.

Comment: web.config `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" res$
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\ImgApp" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile$
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
  <system.web>
</configuration>
` Поставил `<compilation debug="false" />`. Результата нет. Возможно я поставил не туда.